# Не отображается Layout в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlayout, qcheckbox

Я недавно начал изучать *PyQt5* и понадобилось создать `Layout` для чекбоксов. Создал, добавил чекбоксы, и они все в одной точке, сливаются друг с другом. 
Как-то заюзал `setGeometry` на `Layoutуе`, и... он просто пропал).

Прога еще не закончил, но сначала хочу решить это.
Извиняюсь за возможные ошибки в коде.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QCheckBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect

class Macdac(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.UIthing()

    def UIthing(self):
        aboba = QWidget()
        self.setGeometry(331, 466, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Грустно - и точка')
        self.resize(331, 466)

        self.check1chicken = QCheckBox('Куриный бутерброд')
        self.check2cesar = QCheckBox('Цезарь')
        self.check3potato = QCheckBox('Жаренный без масла картофель')
        self.check4voda = QCheckBox("Напиток газированный Красный ключ со вкусом \"Sprite\"")
        self.vlay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlay.setGeometry(QRect(50, 140, 121, 41))

        self.vlay.addWidget(self.check1chicken)
        self.vlay.addWidget(self.check2cesar)
        self.vlay.addWidget(self.check3potato)
        self.vlay.addWidget(self.check4voda)

        aboba.setLayout(self.vlay)
        self.zakaz = QPushButton('Заказать', self)
        self.zakaz.setGeometry(100, 140, 121, 41)

        self.TextThing = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.TextThing.setGeometry(0, 180, 331, 261)


    def run(self):
        self.TextThing.setText('ABOBA')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Macdac()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `aboba` - это локальная переменная и удаляется сборщиком мусора.

Вам надо продлить ее жизнь.

так:

```
aboba = QWidget(self)
```

или так:

```
self.aboba = QWidget()
```

Я позволил себе немного упорядочить ваш код. Если вам что-то не понятно - спросите.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLineEdit, \
        QPushButton, QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QCheckBox,  \
        QGroupBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Macdac(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.checkboxs = []
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        self.ui_thing()

    def ui_thing(self):
#        aboba = QWidget()
        self.aboba = QGroupBox('Какое-то меню')

        self.check1chicken = QCheckBox('Куриный бутерброд')
        self.checkboxs.append(self.check1chicken)
        self.check2cesar = QCheckBox('Цезарь')
        self.checkboxs.append(self.check2cesar)
        self.check3potato = QCheckBox('Жаренный без масла картофель')
        self.checkboxs.append(self.check3potato)
        self.check4voda = QCheckBox("Напиток газированный Красный ключ со вкусом \"Sprite\"")
        self.checkboxs.append(self.check4voda)
        
        self.vlay = QVBoxLayout(self.aboba)
        self.vlay.addWidget(self.check1chicken)
        self.vlay.addWidget(self.check2cesar)
        self.vlay.addWidget(self.check3potato)
        self.vlay.addWidget(self.check4voda)
        
        self.zakaz = QPushButton('Заказать', self)
        self.zakaz.clicked.connect(self.run_zakaz)

        self.textThing = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.aboba)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.zakaz)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.textThing)
        
    def run_zakaz(self):
        self.textThing.clear()
        for checkbox in self.checkboxs:
            if checkbox.isChecked():
                self.textThing.appendPlainText(checkbox.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Macdac()
    win.setWindowTitle('Вкусно – и точка')
    win.setWindowIcon(QIcon("vit.png"))
    win.resize(331, 466)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]